# Passing json from one .NET REST api to another

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json

For reasons I won't get into here, we have 2 .NET Web APIs (A and B). A website sends JSON to A via jQuery's .ajax(), and then A needs to pass it on to B.

In A, I have a model as a parameter in the controller which gets mapped from the json. So:

```
Person: { 
  Surname: "Me",
  FirstName: "Hello" 
}
```

arrives at my controller method as:

```
submitInfo(Person thePerson)
```

How do I make a call from A to B using this model? Do I need to serialize it to json again and then send it to B to get re-mapped? How do I do that?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c) article about how to call a REST api from .NET using query string parameters in the url, but I'm not sure how that works with my model or even when it's serialized to json...

My API controller methods are the same (since it's effectively the same functionality):

```
public IHttpActionResult submitInfo(Person thePerson)
{

}
```

Comment: Show the relevent part from your Api controller

Comment: Done. So I need to send thePerson to B restfully.

Comment: It's still unclear whether `A` and `B` are different controller actions? different controllers or different asp.net projects?

Comment: Completely different web applications. `a/api/submitInfo` vs `b/api/submitInfo`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [parameterbinding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Your request url should be appended with string.Format("?Surname={0}&FirstName={1}", Person.Surname, Person.FirstName)
And on the api action u should use FromUri attribute

so your api knows that thePerson object will be coming from uri parameter i.e.

public IHttpActionResult submitInfo([FromUri]Person thePerson){ }