# How do I access the content of an API response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, mandrill

I've tried implementing the simplest case of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c) with a call to Mandrill's API using the method "ping."  The response should be pong.  Using a valid key, the response seems to work.  However, I am having trouble accessing the content of the response.

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace MandrillAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ping = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/users/ping.json";
            string key = "?key=123";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ping);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(key).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I unpack the response from the call?  Ultimately, I need to harvest emails from the server using the API, so I'll need to somehow preserve the structure of the json objects so I can access the details of the email.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you expect the result(s) to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to read the response as a string:

```
string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

If you want to deserialize to some class (in this case the type `MyClass`):

```
MyClass myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like [JSON.Net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/) to serialize it to a C# object that you can then use.