# How can I take a real-team information to my program? (C#)

Tags: c#

How can, for example, place at my program how much temp is it in England right now by google?
I mean? How can I take real-time information from google/another website and it'll show it at my own program?
c#

Comment: this has to be more specific. there are innumerable ways of querying a DB, using a web service, etc. and then displaying that information to a user. Are you specifically wondering about scraping information off of websites?

Comment: Yes, for example I make a program and I want to show the currect temp at England at the side

Answer (score 1):

You can take real-time info from websites such as google and twitter via web services or APIs:

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public
```

Comment: Thanks.. but how do I use it?
I've never worked with APIs before... I built an offline programs and want to learn a bit more

Comment: The accepted answer to the following stack question should help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c