# Authentification WPF and WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two application on Desktop (WPF) and other WEB (C#).
The user log from the WPF application and a WebBrowser open in a Grid! 
I want the same user log one time from the WPF to the WebBrowser.
Any helps ?

Comment: pass the parameters.. to the constructor through command line argumnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem,you should use Web api for this .When wpf want to save user log, it send the web server.

If your Web app want to access your web application you can still get data by making a request to the web server. This approach is reliable and secure.

You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c)