# C#.NET API Call for PHP Webservice

Tags: c#, php, api

Hi I need to call this PHP API Based URL: 
http://www.webname.com/fc/kaih2h/api.php?

and this is the parameter :

```
uname=client_username&merchantId=client_merch ant_id&sign=client_signature&app=information&action=get_schedule_only&org=BD&des=GMR&dep_date=20110603
```

I have done on PHP with curl.

How I can do handle this on C#.NET

Comment: I think this has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c

Comment: Webclient download string in c#

Comment: WebClient ads = new WebClient();

string response = ads.DownloadString(new Uri("https://xxxx.dddfd.eu/fole.php?pass=Password&base64=" + enc));

Comment: the url need to php url format