# Simplest way to call REST

Tags: c#

I have call to REST service from jscript that works fine:

```
post('/MySite/myFunct', { ID:22 })
```

How to make this call from C# in most native  c# way?

UPD:

I need HTTPS solution also.

UPD:

And I need to use cookies

Comment: Are you just looking for the `HttpClient` class?

Comment: MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make calls to a REST api using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c)

Answer (score 7):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "ID", "22" }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: This works fine! But now I found that I need HTTPS. How to deal with that?

Comment: Need to have a trusted SSL cert or your calls will fail with untrusted error. And addit to client: `WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);`

Comment: HTTPS also works! but now I need to make request, save cookie and use it in another request. How to achieve that?

Comment: `HttpClient` has constructor with `HttpClientHandler`, it has public property `CookieContainer`, set Your cookies here

Answer (score 1):

Old traditional way is using `HttpClient / HttpWebRequest`.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/Test/TestPostData");
request.Method = "POST";
SampleModel model = new SampleModel();
model.PostData = "Test";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
      {
                 string json = serializer.Serialize(model);
                 sw.Write(json);
                 sw.Flush();
      }
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Apart from this I prefer more [**Restclient /Restsharp**](http://restsharp.org/) from nuget.

A simple example of post request will be like this

```
using RestSharp;
using RestTest.Model;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.BaseUrl = "http://carma.org";
    request.Action = "api/1.1/searchPlants";
    request.AddParameter("location", 4338);
    request.AddParameter("limit", 10);
    request.AddParameter("color", "red");
    request.AddParameter("format", "xml");
    request.ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml;
    var plants = client.Execute<PowerPlantsDTO>(request);
    MessageBox.Show(plants.Count.ToString());
}
```

You can use HTTP Verbs directly from call

### A Post example:

```
public void Create(Product product)
{
  var request = new RestRequest("Products", Method.POST); < ----- Use Method.PUT for update
  request.AddJsonBody(product);
  client.Execute(request);
}
```

### A Delete Example

```
public void Delete(int id)
{
  var request = new RestRequest("Products/" + id, Method.DELETE);
  client.Execute(request);
}
```

### For adding header in request

```
request.AddHeader("data", "test");
```

### A Get Request

```
private RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080/api/");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("Products", Method.GET);

RestResponse<YourDataModel> response = client.Execute<YourDataModel>(request);
var name = response.Data.Name;
```