# How to consume web api from Asp.net web api application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

I have my own Web API application in which i want to call the another api which is on server. How can i do that ?

```
var result = url(http://54.193.102.251/CBR/api/User?EmpID=1&ClientID=4&Status=true);
// Something like this.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make calls to a REST api using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx). Here is a sample of `async` method which calls your API:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://54.193.102.251/CBR/api");
// here you can add additional information like authorization or accept headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
   .Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

// you can chose which http method to use
var response = await client.GetAsync("User?EmpID=1&ClientID=4&Status=true");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    return; // process error response here

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // assume your API supports json
// deserialize json here
```