# c# how to get raw xml returned from a url

Tags: c#, xml

I am using this code to load xml into a doc from a url:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);
```

but this fails due to poorly formed xml.

My question is, how do I obtain the xml being returned so that I can debug the cause?

This is not a duplicate. It is completely differen to the duplicate answer given. I need to get the raw data returned from the url but cannot because it is not correct xml.

Comment: can't you hit url directly and read the xml, or use fiddler if need special http headers?

Comment: Try calling the api directly and getting the result: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9620278/616304

Comment: what is the url?

Comment: The classes used to retrieve data from a URL are HttpClient and HttpWebRequest. `XmlDocument` uses HttpWebRequest to get the string and parse it. A simple call to [HttpClient.GetStringAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netframework-4.7) will return the URL's content as a string

Comment: can't hit api directly as api is behind firewall and need to access via specific ip (which can only currently do via code). will try HttpClient.GetStringAsync()