# API GET request from my api to another api?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, controller

I'm trying to create a backend that sends a GET request to another API.

For example:

My API: `localhost:3000/` 
Route: `/getdata/data1` 
Other API: `api.com/target/data`

(This is a fake URL, just assume that this route has the data that I want)

How can I send a get request to that API from my API? `Ajax.get`?

Comment: The other API is in the same web application?

Comment: Different. Its another webapp. I essentialy want my api to request the other api’s data

Comment: And the response from my api is = response from other api (json data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make calls to a REST api using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c)

Comment: https://www.rapiddg.com/blog/calling-rest-api-nodejs-script

Comment: The easiest way is to install a module like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and use it to make the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module in node, or use a third-party package such as [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

## HTTP

An example of using the built in [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module e.g:

```
// The 'https' module can also be used
const http = require('http');

// Example route
app.get('/some/api/endpoint',  (req, res) => {

    http.get('http://someapi.com/api/endpoint', (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // Concatinate each chunk of data
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });

        // Once the response has finished, do something with the result
        resp.on('end', () => {
          res.json(JSON.parse(data));
        });

        // If an error occured, return the error to the user
      }).on("error", (err) => {
        res.json("Error: " + err.message);
      });
});
```

## Request

Alternatively, a third party package such as [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) can be used.

First install request:

`npm install -s request`

And then change your route to something like this:

```
const request = require('request');

// Example route
app.get('/some/api/endpoint',  (req, res) => {

    request('http://someapi.com/api/endpoint',  (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            // If there is an error, tell the user 
            res.send('An erorr occured')
        }
        // Otherwise do something with the API data and send a response
        else {
            res.send(body)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js, use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Example:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Replace http://www.google.com with your URL. You'll need to see if you need to authorize with the other API; otherwise you will get HTTP 401.