# How to access REST API endpoints made by ExpressJS in a C# code

Tags: c#, node.js, rest, express

I have set up a backend server with multiple endpoints using NodeJS with the ExpressJS framework. These REST Api Endpoints are connected to a Mongodb Database.

Due to project requirements, I had to write some code on C# that will also be calling and posting data into the database.
However, I am now having trouble accessing the collections created by the ExpressJS Api Endpoint on my C# code.

May I know how is it normally done? Eg. how do I create a GET request from C# to access a collection created by ExpressJS
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag which will help you generate your c# client code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are really looking for... 
But for that you will need your express server running/online, so you may consume the api you have set it up. 
And for C# part, you will need to do something that C# will hit/consume the endpoints from express server.

I think this links will be very helpful, I hope to be of a help for you. 
[How do I make calls to a REST api using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c) 
 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#send-a-get-request-to-retrieve-a-resource