# Xamarin.forms Get the token after logging in

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Sorry for my poor language. I would like to know how to get the token after logging in in xamarin.forms. I enter my email and password in postman, it generates the token visible at the bottom
[image]

I authorize myself by entering Bearer + token
[image]

Comment: Would [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c) help?

Comment: it appears the token is returned in the response body

Comment: Xamarin.Essentials WebAuthenticator/OAuth2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=ios#using-webauthenticator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpClient to [Consume a RESTful Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest#consuming-the-web-service) and get the token from the response:

```
public async void test() {

    var client = new HttpClient();

    string jsonData = @"{""username"" : ""myusername"", ""password"" : ""mypassword""}";

    var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("your request url", content);

    // this result string should be something like: "{"token":"rgh2ghgdsfds"}"
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: I want to format this line of code so that "email.Text" is in quotation marks, but so that I can also enter text for this:  string jsonData = @"{""username"" : ""myusername"", ""password"" : ""mypassword""}";

Comment: I answered this question in your another thread. Please check.

Comment: If my solution works for you, can you please accept both answer (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).