# How to call web API from windows service with id c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I'm new in working with api and i want to create windows service to call the some api like
`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/` and get the record with id of `1`
what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion is use Http Client Requests and Response.
Here is the reference How to call Web API from Http Client
[How do I make calls to a REST API using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c)