# Open Pdf From API On Winforms Project in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have an API that opens a pdf file in a browser, I want to call that programmatically from another WinForms project(Both in the same solution).

Here is the Controller and setups:

`app.UseCors();`

```
[EnableCors("*")]
[Route("api/pdfcreator")]
[ApiController]
public class PdfCreatorController : Controller
{
    private IConverter _converter;
    public PdfCreatorController(IConverter converter)
    {
        _converter = converter;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreatePDF()
    {
        var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
        {
            ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
            Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
            Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10 },
            DocumentTitle = "PDF Report",
            //Out = @"D:\PDFCreator\Employee_Report.pdf"
        };
        var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
        {
            PagesCount = true,
            HtmlContent = TemplateGenerator.GetHTMLString(),
            WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8", UserStyleSheet = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets", "styles.css") },
            HeaderSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true },
            FooterSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Line = true, Center = "Report Footer" }
        };
        var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
        {
            GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
            Objects = { objectSettings }
        };
        //_converter.Convert(pdf);
        var file = _converter.Convert(pdf);
        //return Ok("Successfully created PDF document.");
        return File(file, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Here is how I want to call it:

```
getApi("http://localhost:44344/api/pdfcreator");



public string GetApi(string ApiUrl)
    {
        var responseString = "";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiUrl);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        using (var response1 = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return responseString;

    }
```

But the response here is a string, while we are interested in calling the API only!

How to do this?

Considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c), It is not clear how to send the response to the browser again after parsing it!

Comment: Are you asking how to get the response as bytes so you can parse the PDF?  You can probably pass the `Stream` from `GetResponseStream` on its own as the response stream to the browser as long as the content type is still "application/pdf".

Comment: Of course it's string - `public string GetApi(string ApiUrl)` - what do you really want as the output? A file? Bytes as @IllusiveBrian mentions? What do you mean by ` interested in calling the API only`? Do you want nothing returned?

Comment: The API does what it is supposed to do, which is showing the pdf file in a browser when we type the URL in the address bar, I want to trigger that action or event in a winform application. I have two options:1-Make the api returns byte[] as suggested by @IllusiveBrian, but how then could we show that file in browser? 2- Try to simulate the event of typing in the browser!

Comment: I changed the title to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: What do you want to happend in the Winforms application when you get the file from the API?

Comment: @Magnus Thank you, simply show the file in browser.

Comment: Doesn't the API require authentication?

Comment: @CodeCaster In this case no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from your comment in the question I assume you want to show the file in the browser from the winforms application.

Then you can do this. It will launch the default browser and go to the file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:44344/api/pdfcreator");
```

Comment: But what if the API requires authentication, which is provided through the WinForms app?

Comment: Thank you Magnus, this is exactly what I want!!