# How do I create a REST client in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core

This is the code of my .NET core 3.1 console application:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using NumbersConsole.Models;

namespace NumbersConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static void ShowcaseNumber(NumberModel numberModel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number: " + numberModel.Number.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Fact: " + numberModel.Text);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task<NumberModel> GetNumberModelAsync()
        {
            NumberModel number = null;
            var path = new Uri("http://numbersapi.com/41");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                number = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<NumberModel>();
            }
            return number;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            NumberModel number = new NumberModel();
            number = await GetNumberModelAsync();
            ShowcaseNumber(numberModel);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my NumberModel.cs:

```
namespace NumbersConsole.Models
{
    public class NumberModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Somehow `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path)` does not give a response but instead the program just exits.

I have tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17459045) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). I have tried multiple variations of this line of code like
`HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(path).Result;`

Does someone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You aren't `awaiting` the `async` method. So the `main` method exits. You can change `main` to have a signature of `static async Task Main(string[] args)` and `await RunAsync();` If you're using C# 7.1 or later. which in .Net Core 3.1 the default is C# 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you aren't `awaiting` the `async` method, so the calling thread continues execution in `main` once the `await` is hit in your `RunAsync` method, allowing the application to exit without completing.

As of C# 7.1 you can use an `async` version of the `main` method, and since you are targeting .Net Core 3.1, the default is C# 8, so the following should be valid:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await RunAsync();
}
```